# Webfm and views; can I create a view that has a list of links to the files?

Tags: files

Really new to Drupal and getting a little lost on this one. I want to create a view of files that are listed in webfm. These files will all be pdfs. Is this even possible.

My aim is to use standard drupal 6 modules to allow the users to upload reports in pdf and list them in a view. But the view needs to link directly to the file. 
Another option is to use nodes to display pdf files. But this has to be in a way that end users can easily upload and create a node that displays the pdf.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually just started working on this myself this morning.  The answer is yes, you can, but as far as I've read into it, the view can't be part of another view, i.e., you have to create a separate view just for WebFM files.  You'll see it when you go to Views > Add > View Type.

Like I said, I just started working on this this morning, so I haven't gotten any further than that, but HTH.  Maybe post progress here for sharing?  Funny that your question came up in teh Googles.

Answer (score 0):

I've got something working, hope this helps someone.

First I installed the cck toolkit. and enabled filefield and all it's requirements.

Enabled upload and installed views.

next created a custom node type pdf.

Added a new file field.

Then created a veiw showing all nodes of type pdf and listed the file field.

If you need more detail let me know